# subscribing to event causes 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'

Tags: web-of-things

Tried to make [example-event.ts](https://github.com/eclipse/thingweb.node-wot/blob/611d927498ccbf37500247c30cf7eaf77ddad8e0/packages/examples/src/scripts/example-event.ts) work as HTTP Server. The example is a simple counter. You can subscribe to the count as an event.
It works until a client asks a second time for the value (longpoll).

```
EventSource ready
Emitted change  1
[binding-http] HttpServer on port 8080 received 'GET /eventsource' from [::ffff:192.168.0.5]:58268
[binding-http] HttpServer on port 8080 replied with '200' to [::ffff:192.168.0.5]:58268
[binding-http] HttpServer on port 8080 received 'GET /eventsource/events/onchange' from [::ffff:192.168.0.5]:58268
[core/exposed-thing] ExposedThing 'EventSource' subscribes to event 'onchange'
[core/content-serdes] ContentSerdes serializing to application/json
Emitted change  2
[binding-http] HttpServer on port 8080 replied with '200' to [::ffff:192.168.0.5]:58268
[binding-http] HttpServer on port 8080 closed Event connection
[core/exposed-thing] ExposedThing 'EventSource' unsubscribes from event 'onchange'
[binding-http] HttpServer on port 8080 received 'GET /eventsource/events/onchange' from [::ffff:192.168.0.5]:58268
[core/exposed-thing] ExposedThing 'EventSource' subscribes to event 'onchange'
[core/content-serdes] ContentSerdes serializing to application/json
[core/content-serdes] ContentSerdes serializing to application/json
Emitted change  3
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at writeAfterEnd (_http_outgoing.js:694:15)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:815:7)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (C:\xxx\node_modules\@node-wot\binding-http\dist\http-server.js:721:45)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (C:\xxx\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:242:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (C:\xxx\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:189:22)
    at Subscriber._next (C:\xxx\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:129:26)
    at Subscriber.next (C:\xxx\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js:93:18)
    at Subject.next (C:\xxx\node_modules\rxjs\Subject.js:55:25)
    at Object.ExposedThing.emitEvent (C:\xxx\node_modules\@node-wot\core\dist\exposed-thing.js:53:50)
Emitted 'error' event on ServerResponse instance at:
    at writeAfterEndNT (_http_outgoing.js:753:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:83:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
```

I am a little confused by all the subscribing and unsubscribing, but this is maybe because of longpoll is used.

my code:

server side:

```
Servient = require('@node-wot/core').Servient;
HttpServer = require('@node-wot/binding-http').HttpServer;
Helpers = require('@node-wot/core').Helpers;

// create Servient add HTTP binding with port configuration
let servient = new Servient();
servient.addServer(new HttpServer({}));

// internal state, not exposed as Property
let counter = 0;

servient.start().then((WoT) => {
  WoT.produce({
    title: 'EventSource',
    events: {
      onchange: {
        data: { type: 'integer' },
      },
    },
  })
    .then((thing) => {
      console.log('Produced ' + thing.getThingDescription().title);

      thing.expose().then(() => {
        console.info(thing.getThingDescription().title + ' ready');

        setInterval(() => {
          ++counter;
          thing.emitEvent('onchange', counter);
          console.info('Emitted change ', counter);
        }, 5000);
      });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
});
```

cient side:

```
const servient = new Wot.Core.Servient();
servient.addClientFactory(new Wot.Http.HttpClientFactory());
const helpers = new Wot.Core.Helpers(servient);

const addr ='http://192.168.0.5:8080/eventsource';
getTd(addr);

function getTd(addr) {
  servient.start().then((thingFactory) => {
    helpers
      .fetch(addr)
      .then((td) => {
        thingFactory.consume(td).then((thing) => {
          showEvents(thing);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        window.alert('Could not fetch TD.\n' + error);
      });
  });
}

function showEvents(thing) {
  let td = thing.getThingDescription();
  for (let evnt in td.events) {
    if (td.events.hasOwnProperty(evnt)) {

      document.getElementById("events").innerHTML = "waiting...";

      thing
        .subscribeEvent(evnt, (res) => {
          document.getElementById("events").innerHTML = res;
        })
        .catch((err) => window.alert('error: ' + err));
    }
  }
}
```

The problem also occurs if I'm using [example-event-client.ts](https://github.com/eclipse/thingweb.node-wot/blob/611d927498ccbf37500247c30cf7eaf77ddad8e0/packages/examples/src/scripts/example-event-client.ts) or just send GET requests to "http://192.168.0.5:8080/eventsource/events/onchange" using the browser.

What do I have to do to make the example work?

Comment: Could you give further information about the following:
- Are you installing node-wot from npm or the master branch in GitHub?
- Have you tried the counter example which also has events?

Comment: @EgeKorkan node-wot is installed from npm. Just tried the counter example - same proplem occurs.

Comment: @EgeKorkan any ideas?

Comment: I will look this into detail since we had solved this some time ago. Have you used version 0.7.8 with core and HTTP binding?

Comment: @EgeKorkan ...yes, I have used version 0.7.8 with core and HTTP binding - thank you for looking

Comment: Sadly we haven't published the new version yet. It should be out soon. Meanwhile, you can build node-wot locally as described in the main readme.

Comment: @Cristiano as I'm running into problems over and over again by building it locally. Is there chance that the new version will be published within next week?

Comment: There might be the concrete possibility that we'll publish the 0.8.0 within next week. At least we want to experiment with it in the next plugfest! which is planned for this month. Meanwhile, can I ask you what is going wrong in building locally? Have you considered to open issue on the repository?

Comment: 0.8.0 is now out can you test the example again? @mo_le